# Как в Java Servlets прописать путь для папки resources/css и js?

Tags: веб-программирование, servlet, resources

У меня настроено, что при попадании на "/", сразу перекидывает на "/home", но в таком случае не подгружаются логотипы, стили и js.  Использую голые сервлеты + подключен maven. Вот мой сервлет для редиректа:

```
@WebServlet("/")
public class ServletDispatcher extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
response.sendRedirect("/home");
    }
}
```

**Как правильно прописать в сервлетах, чтобы папка с логотипами/ресурсами и js имели доступ?**

Моя структура:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос как Вы прописывали, или хотите прописать. Используете какой-нибудь фреймверк (Spring например или голые сервлеты)? И какие запросы обрабатывает сервлет (напр. /*)?

Comment: @MrFylypenko, добавил.